# Makefile error when trying to see output in ubuntu windows

Tags: python, ubuntu, unix, makefile

I am extremely new to python and unix and my assignment for class is to make a makefile called python_program for a simple program called python_program.py . Ive looked on the other threads related to this type of question but I dont know enough to understand most of the things they are saying. When I run make in ubuntu it does create the new python_program file with the printed "Python is a fun language to learn" but when I do the command ./python_program it gives me the error code below. I appreciate all the help and advice given

python_program.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    print("Python is a fun language to learn")


main()
```

My Makefile

```
python_program: python_program.py
    python  python_program.py > python_program
    chmod +x python_program.py
```

I've tried many different version to create the MakeFile and this is my most recent one, but eachtime I run it it creates a blank python_program file or it gives me an error code in the Ubunut command line.

Error Code:

```
./python_program: line 1: Python: command not found
```

Just some extra information as to why I have to do this and the exact objective of this code

```
The Python Makefile must use the file python_program.py to create an executable file called python_program.

Assume that your Python Makefile is called Makefile and is in the same directory as the python_program.py, and therefore, when you run make in that directory, your Python Makefile will create a python_program executable.

Also, your Python Makefile must recreate python_program when python_program.py changes and you run make again.

This means that:

Run make.
Execute ./python_program.
Edit the source code python_program.py (change the strings, for instance).
Run make.
Execute ./python_program and verify that the changes you made in step 3 are reflected.
There are several ways to approach this (because there’s nothing to compile). For instance, you can take advantage of the shebang functionality, which allows a file that can be interpreted to be executed. This requires that the file is executable (chmod +x filename).
```

Comment: Why are you trying to execute a file that contains the string `Python is a fun language to learn`?

Comment: In fact why do you need a makefile at all?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: its for an assignment for school where I was given the program_python.py file and i need to turn it  into an executable using a MakeFile.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what you need to do.

Your Python program `python_program.py` must create a file, `python_program`, which is a valid executable program.  Just adding `chmod +x` to a file will tell the computer it's an executable program, but that doesn't mean it's a *valid* executable program.

You could have a PDF file containing a letter to your roommate, and run `chmod +x` on it, and then the computer would let you "run" it, but it wouldn't actually work, because a letter to your roommate is not a valid executable program.

In your example above you have created a Python program that writes out a file that contains the string *Python is a fun language to learn*.  But, just a like a letter to your roommate, a file containing the string *Python is a fun language to learn* is not a valid executable program.

So, when you try to run it, it fails.

You need to modify your `python_program.py` so that the file it generates, `python_program`, is an actual valid executable program.  Your quoted text above doesn't give you any directions as to what form that might take, so it's up to you.  But it can't just be the equivalent of a letter to your roommate.